# What is this yellow thing with a pipe?

Tags: command-line, ls

I noticed that `/var/spool/nullmailer` directory contains a weird `trigger` entity which is displayed in yellow and has a “|” suffix.

It doesn't seem to be a directory (at least I can't `cd` into it), and when I try to open it with `vi`, the console freezes.

What is that thing?

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is a [named-pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Unix) - one of the 7 types of file in Unix. The `p` in `prw--w--w-` confirms it is a named-pipe.

You can write to the pipe from one side and read the data from the other side:

```
$ mkfifo mypipe
$ cat mypipe
```

In another terminal

```
$ cat > mypipe
Hello from the other side
What's up?
```

Whatever you type in here will appear in the other terminal.

`l` is an alias to `ls -CF` and `ll` is alias to `ls -alFh`.
According to the man page

```
-F, --classify
    append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

So for a named-pipe `|` is appended to the filename.

Answer (score 3):

You can identify any 'file' on a linux system by using the command file, followed by the file name.

```
file "trigger"
```

Would tell you it's a named pipe.

Comment: The filename doesn't include the pipe symbol, so it should be `file trigger`. This can be seen with `mkfifo trigger; ll trigger; file "trigger|"`

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex good catch, i didn't notice that is just weird formating they have in ls !